# Why is there No more Kubernetes for Latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install Kubernetes on Ubuntu 20.04 but the latest release is for Ubuntu 16.04. I am following the official tutorial by kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/

Is it discontinued for Ubuntu?

Comment: Likely the upstream disagreements in Debian about vendoring k8s dependencies. Lot of dev discussion about whether or not k8s should even be included in a stable release. OS provided packages are probably the least-common way to provision a cluster

Comment: Related to that, kubernetes binaries are statically linked golang programs, and thus have very little in the way of "dependency upon Ubuntu whatever" so it's likely fine to just use the 16.04 repo

Comment: Yes I tried adding the 16.04 repos, I was trying to be careful not to break my setup.

Answer (score 1):

As @jordanm and @mdaniel mentioned

> likely the upstream disagreements in Debian about vendoring k8s dependencies. Lot of dev discussion about whether or not k8s should even be included in a stable release. OS provided packages are probably the least-common way to provision a cluster.
>
> Related to that, kubernetes binaries are statically linked golang
> programs, and thus have very little in the way of "dependency upon.  Ubuntu whatever" so it's likely fine to just use the 16.04 repo.

Read: [minikube-ubuntu-20.04](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-kubernetes-with-minikube-ubuntu-20-04/).

See also: [kubernetes-on-ubuntu](https://medium.com/@vishal.sharma./installing-configuring-kubernetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-hosts-f37b959c8410).

Comment: Yes I did, all the repos were of xenial and I was afraid that it will break my setup, I did and everything works fine.

Comment: So if solution helped please upvote and accept it to be more visible for community.